# Why should preprocessing be done on CPU rather than GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

The [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide) advises to do the preprocessing on CPU rather that on GPU. The listed reasons are

1. This prevent the data from going from CPU to GPU to CPU to GPU back again.
2. This frees the GPU of these tasks to focus on training.

I am not sure to understand either arguments.

1. Why would preprocessing send the result back to the CPU, esp. if all nodes are on GPU? Why preprocessing operations and not any other operation on the graph, why are they/should they be special?
2. Even though I understand the rationale behind putting the CPU to work rather than keeping it idle, compared to the huge convolutions and other gradient backpropagation a training step has to do, I would have assumed that random cropping, flip and other standard preprocessing steps on the input images should be nowhere near in term of computation needs, and should be executed in a fraction of the time. Even if we think of preprocessing as mostly moving things around (crop, flips), I think GPU memory should be faster for that. Yet doing preprocessing on the CPU can yield a *6+-fold increase* in throughput according to the same guide.

I am assuming of course that preprocessing does not result in a drastic decrease in size of the data (e.g. supersampling or cropping to a much smaller size), in which case the gain in transfer time to the device is obvious. I suppose these are rather extreme cases and do not constitute the basis for the above recommendation.

Can somebody make sense out of this?

Answer (score 9):

It is based on the same logic on how CPU and GPU works. GPU is good at doing repetitive parallelised tasks very well, whereas CPU is good at other computations, which require more processing capabilities.

For example, consider a program, which accepts inputs of two integers from the user and runs a for-loop for 1 Million times to sum the two numbers.

How we can achieve this with the combination of CPU and GPU processing?

We do the initial data (two user input integers) intercept part from the user on CPU and then send the two numbers to GPU and the for-loop to sum the numbers runs on the GPU because that is the repetitive, parallelizable yet simple computation part, which GPU is better at. [Although this example wasn't really exactly related to tensorflow but this concept is the heart of all CPU and GPU processing. Regarding your query: Processing abilities like random cropping, flip and other standard preprocessing steps on the input images might not be computational intensive but GPU doesn't excel in such kind of interrupt related computation either.]

Another thing we need to keep in mind that the **latency between CPU and GPU also plays a key role here**. **Copying and transferring data to and fro CPU and GPU is expensive** if compared to the transfer of data between different cache levels inside CPU.

As Dey, 2014 [[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265851311_EFFICIENT_DATA_INPUTOUTPUT_IO_FOR_FINITE_DIFFERENCE_TIME_DOMAIN_FDTD_COMPUTATION_ON_GRAPHICS_PROCESSING_UNIT_GPU)] have mentioned:

> When a parallelized program is computed on the GPGPU, first the data
>   is copied from the memory to the GPU and after computation the data is
>   written back to the memory from the GPU using the PCI-e bus (Refer to
>   Fig. 1.8). Thus for every computation, data has to be copied to and
>   fro device-host-memory. Although the computation is very fast in
>   GPGPU, but because of the gap between the device-host-memory due to
>   communication via PCI-e, the bottleneck in the performance is
>   generated.

[image]

For this reason it is advisable that:

> You do the preprocessing on CPU, where the CPU does the initial
>   computation, prepares and sends the rest of the repetitive
>   parallelised tasks to the GPU for further processing.

I once developed a buffer mechanism to increase the data processing between CPU and GPU, and henceforth reduce the negative effects of latency between CPU and GPU. Have a look at this thesis to gain a better understanding of this issue:

[EFFICIENT DATA INPUT/OUTPUT (I/O) FOR FINITE DIFFERENCE TIME DOMAIN (FDTD) COMPUTATION ON GRAPHICS PROCESSING UNIT (GPU)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265851311_EFFICIENT_DATA_INPUTOUTPUT_IO_FOR_FINITE_DIFFERENCE_TIME_DOMAIN_FDTD_COMPUTATION_ON_GRAPHICS_PROCESSING_UNIT_GPU)

Now, to answer your question:

**Why would preprocessing send the result back to the CPU, esp. if all nodes are on GPU?**

As quoted from the performance guide of Tensorflow [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHMC4.png)],

> When preprocessing occurs on the GPU the flow of data is CPU -> GPU
>   (preprocessing) -> CPU -> GPU (training). The data is bounced back and
>   forth between the CPU and GPU.

If you remember the dataflow diagram between the CPU-Memory-GPU mentioned above, the reason for doing the preprocessing on CPU improves performance because:

- After computation of nodes on GPU, data is sent back on the memory
  and CPU fetches that memory for further processing. GPU does not have
  enough memory on-board (on GPU itself) to keep all the data on it for computational prupose. So
  back-and-forth of data is inevitable. To optimise this data flow, you
  do preprocessing on CPU, then the data (for training purposes), which is prepared for parallelizable tasks, is sent to the memory and GPU
  fetches that preprocessed data and work on it.

In the performance guide itself it also mentions that by doing this, and having an efficient input pipeline, you won't starve either CPU or GPU or both, which itself proves the aforementioned logic. Again, in the same performance doc, you will also see the mentioning of

> If your training loop runs faster when using SSDs vs HDDs for storing
>   your input data, you could could be I/O bottlenecked.If this is the
>   case, you should pre-process your input data, creating a few large
>   TFRecord files.

This again tries to mention the same CPU-Memory-GPU performance bottleneck, which is mentioned above.

Hope this helps and in case you need more clarification (on CPU-GPU performance), do not hesitate to drop a message!

**References:**

[[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265851311_EFFICIENT_DATA_INPUTOUTPUT_IO_FOR_FINITE_DIFFERENCE_TIME_DOMAIN_FDTD_COMPUTATION_ON_GRAPHICS_PROCESSING_UNIT_GPU)] Somdip Dey, *EFFICIENT DATA INPUT/OUTPUT (I/O) FOR FINITE DIFFERENCE TIME DOMAIN (FDTD) COMPUTATION ON GRAPHICS PROCESSING UNIT (GPU)*, 2014

[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHMC4.png)] Tensorflow Performance Guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.
 1) Why is data sent back to CPU? You are saying that the GPU does not hold enough memory for that, but A) is it really the case, esp. since input data can be discarded after preprocessing, and B) why would tensorflow send data back to CPU *by default* when it could simply do it when it doesn't have enough memory (this functionality is already present in tensorflow). 2) Why would CPU be faster than GPU for crops, flips, adding noise? Those seem parallelizable. And even then, would it be *that much faster* to need sending back data to host?

Comment: Refer to the image provided in my answer. Can you notice, how Main memory, CPU and GPU are connected? Main memory (RAM) is not connected to GPU directly. Let's assume you want to process x amount of data on GPU which has an inbuilt memory capacity of y, whereas x is lot more than y. Now if you have to compute x on GPU, you have to copy y amount of data onto GPU first, send it back to RAM and then copy (x-y) amount of data from RAM and then bring it onto GPU and process it.

Comment: Every transaction to fetch memory from RAM to GPU and forth is expensive because of the system architecture. That why data back and forth from Memory-CPU-GPU is inevitable. (Answer to your question 1)

Comment: Answer to your question2: Think when you are doing preprocessing such as cropping, etc. When you are viewing that on your monitor, behind the scene everything is processed on/by the RAM and the CPU. Of course GPU sometimes can do many stuff faster than CPU but if you understood the memory association mentioned above then to preprocess such as cropping, you need to spend expensive time to first send that data to GPU, processing it and then retrieve the processed data from GPU and put it on to the RAM to be copied over to the HD or for further processing.

Comment: Whatsoever, when CPU is closer to RAM and have easier access than GPU then why waste time by doing al these on GPU. Memory transaction is much more inportant here and need to be managed properly. Have a look at this for reference on how GPU works: http://www.nvidia.com/object/what-is-gpu-computing.html

Comment: Why not simply send the data to GPU memory, do the precomputations there, and directly feed the results to the network, without sending back anything to the host?

Comment: Simply, because that is not how modern computer system architecture works. Nvidia has been working on their GPU Tegra to do processing directly on GPU and GPU's RAM, but I can not provide you with their progress in that issue. In modern Computer architecture, whenever a processing is done, the main memory is the RAM attached to the CPU and CPU and GPU are connected via PCI-e bus. Thats how the architecture is. You may find it little beneficial to read up on computer architecture first. You can also read the first chapter of my thesis to get a brief idea as well.

Comment: Tensorflow keeps this architecture in mind so that Tensorflow can be implemented on any platform and still gain performance regardless.

Comment: When tensorflow does a convolution to some input data, it does not send the result back to the host before feeding the next convolution layer, does it? So why would it have to be different for preprocessing?

Comment: You mentioned, tensorflow does a convolution to some input data. Now, whether it sends the data back to the host or not to feed the next convolution layer would depend on 1) Your implementation of algorithm, 2) Amount of data being processed. If the amount of data being processed is large then the data will be sent back to the host memory (I mean RAM) and then onto a disk.

Comment: But if the amount of data being processed fits the GPU memory then there is not need to send the data back and forth during computation. Another thing, is your impmentation of the alogrithm. If you are keeping the global variable on CPU such that data from one convolution layer needs to update these global variables on CPU, so that it ca be forwarded to next layer, then the exchange of data between host-memory, host and GPU is inevitable.

Comment: But if your implementation is written in such a way that the update of one convolution layer is directly passed to the next layer without updating the variables/parameters on the CPU, then you get the idea that the whole execution is done on the GPU itself. But in this case, you still have to remeber how much memory is actually availale on the GPU so that you dont have to send data back and forth host-memory to complete the execution.

Comment: In "Convolutional Neural Training" tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn, you will see that it is mentioned, "..Prefetching queues for input data to isolate the model from disk latency and expensive image pre-processing." - which implies the afforementioned logic. You will also see mentioning of "..Reading images from disk and distorting them can use a non-trivial amount of processing time.

Comment: To prevent these operations from slowing down training, we run them inside 16 separate threads which continuously fill a TensorFlow queue." - which again inferes that the image to be processed is loaded from the disk to the RAM and then used further by CPU or GPU or both, depending on your algortihm/the algorithm you are implementing.

Comment: You will also notice mentioning of "Be careful not to run the evaluation and training binary on the same GPU or else you might run out of memory. Consider running the evaluation on a separate GPU if available or suspending the training binary while running the evaluation on the same GPU." - which proves the limited availability of memory on GPU given the huge evaluation and training data points. Thus, the tutorial asks you to segregate them on to two different GPUs.

Comment: Again, if you notice the "Training a Model Using Multiple GPU Cards" section of the same tutorial, you will see that there is mentioning of -
"Note that each GPU computes inference as well as the gradients for a unique batch of data. This setup effectively permits dividing up a larger batch of data across the GPUs.

Comment: This setup requires that all GPUs share the model parameters. A well-known fact is that transferring data to and from GPUs is quite slow. For this reason, we decide to store and update all model parameters on the CPU (see green box). A fresh set of model parameters is transferred to the GPU when a new batch of data is processed by all GPUs." - which inferes that you put the global variables on the CPU and the updates is passed from the GPU to the CPU in order to update the global variables.

Comment: Now, there has been many places where the same issue of data transfer and IO bottleneck between Memory-CPU-GPU has been mentioned all over Tensorflow tutorials/documentation. I can understand that it might be little difficult to grasp this concept until and unless you know how dataflow atakes place in a Computer Architecture. Until and unless you understand this concept porperly, it might be little difficult for you to understand the Performance tips on Tensorflow.

Comment: SO i can only suggest that you would need to read up on Computer System Architecture, and difference between CPU vs GPU computation.
NOW, if you see the length of this whole answer, I would say it itself has become a Memory-CPU-GPU wiki article along with wiki article on  dataflow and effective implementation of algorithm in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 2):

I quote at first two arguments from the [performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide) and I think 
your two questions concern these two arguments respectively.

> The data is bounced back and forth between the CPU and GPU. ...
>   Another benefit is preprocessing on the CPU frees GPU time to focus on training.

(1) Operations like file `reader`, `queue` and `dequeue` can only be performed in CPU, operations like `reshape`, `cast`, `per_image_standardization` can be in CPU or GPU. So a wild guess for your first question: if the code doesn't specify `/cpu:0`, the program will perform in CPU by readers, then pre-process images in GPU, and finally enqueue and dequeue in CPU. (Not sure I am correct. waiting for an expert to verify...)

(2) For the second question, I have the same doubt too. When you train a large network, most of time is spent on the huge convolutions and the gradient computation, not on preprocessing images. However, when they mean *6X+ increase in samples/sec processed*, I think they mean the training on MNIST, where a small network is usually used. So that makes sense. Smaller convolutions spend much less time so the time spent on preprocessing is relatively large. *6X+ increase* is possible for this case. But `preprocessing on the CPU frees GPU time to focus on training` is a reasonable explanation.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: What you have mentioned is the fact itself but not the reason.