# How to make loading/preprocessing batch data and training parallel in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I was wondering if we can load and prepossess next batch data while training current batch in Tensorflow.

My model requires to load multiple images from different source and do some preprocessing for each training operation, and this whole process is pretty slow. It takes my computer 1.4 seconds to load/process a batch of training data and 1.6 seconds to train on GPU. I am thinking if there is a way that allows me to load next batch data during training thus I can accelerate training process in a significant margin.

BTW, I am already multi threading my preprocessing function.

In training stage, a simplified version of my code is pasted below:

```
with tf.Session as sess:
    ......
    ......
    while step < max_global_step:
        ......
        ......
        #This line takes 1.4 seconds to execute
        images_batch = load_batch_data(*batch_image_paths)
        feed = {train_batch, images_batch}
        #This line takes bout 1.6 seconds to run
        loss, summary, step= sess.run([loss, summary, global_step], feed_dict=feed)
        ......
        ......
    ......
    ......
```

So generally the program will spend 1.4 seconds running `images_batch = load_batch_data(*batch_image_paths)` and 1.6 seconds for `loss, summary, step= sess.run([loss, summary, global_step], feed_dict=feed)`

intuition told me there should have some way to make a double-buffer-like mechanism for each step I read data and put it to buffer 0 and use data in buffer 1 to feed into network, and toggle buffer, but how to achieve that?

Or, is there any way to improve total training cost in situations like mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code is not possible to execute. Maybe an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can help people to understand better your question.

To answer your question, there are two possibilities:

1. The program is launched in CPU. Then the problem is quite simple. I noticed that you were probably using `feed_dict` to load data. There are two other approaches to load data, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data). You can try to use `tf.train.QueueRunner` or some wrapped functions of `QueueRunner` to prefetch data and it may work well for your problem. See the link and you can find everything. But some efforts are needed for understanding the mechanism, at least for me.
2. If the program is launched in GPU. Then the problem you met may be related to the communication between CPU and GPU, see the suggestion by Tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide) and an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44377741/4834515) for explaining the reason. But I think the problem in your situation can be resolved by `QueueRunner`.

Comment: Yeah, I think you have solved my problem, I should witch to ```QueueRunner``` instead of feeding.